# Erro de redirecionamento de login iphone - Correlation failed

Tags: auth, asp-net-core

Estou com problemas ao fazer login pelo google e facebook quando acesso através de um iphone, após eu autenticar minha conta, no google por exemplo, o callback não é chamado gerando uma exceção.

O login funciona assim:

1. O cliente clica no botão (google)
2. A função ExternalLogin é chamada, passando o provider(google) e a url de redirecionamento
3. A autenticação é feita e a url de redirecionamento é chamada.

A aplicação utiliza netCore 2.1, quando eu acesso a aplicação utilizando um navegador desktop ou pelo celular utilizando android tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas quando tento fazer o login pelo iphone utilizando o facebook ou google é gerado uma exceção "Correlation failed", como mostra a imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Startup.cs**

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlite("Data Source=Auth.db"));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            string clienteID = System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached ? "Meu-id" : "Meu-id";
            string clienteSECRET = System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached ? "Meu-id" : "Meu-id";
            string facebookID = "Meu-id";
            string facebookSECRET = "Meu-id";

            services
                .AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
                {
                    sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Home/Index";
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                })
                .AddGoogle("Google", googleOptions =>
                {
                    googleOptions.ClientId = clienteID;
                    googleOptions.ClientSecret = clienteSECRET;
                    googleOptions.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";
                    googleOptions.ClaimActions.Clear();
                    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
                    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
                    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "given_name");
                    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "family_name");
                    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:profile", "link");
                    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
                    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:picture", "picture", "url");
                    googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:locale", "locale", "string");
                })
                .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
                {
                    facebookOptions.AppId = facebookID;
                    facebookOptions.AppSecret = facebookSECRET;
                });
                
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddProgressiveWebApp();
            //services.ConfigureExternalCookie(options =>
            //{
            //    // Other options
            //    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            //});
            //services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            //{
            //    // Other options
            //    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            //});
        }
        
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions()
            {
                MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "LoginEmpresa",
                    template: "{Empresa}",
                    //defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "LoginPage" });
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
        }
    }
```

**ExternalLogin**

```
     [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            // Reque;;st a redirect to the external login provider.
            var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Account", new { returnUrl });
            AuthenticationProperties properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
            try
            {
                //properties.AllowRefresh = true;
                return Challenge(properties, provider);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MetodosAuxiliares.SaveExceptionError(e, "ExternalLogin/try");
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro de login estava ocorrendo por conta de um bug no Mac OSX e o IOS, o que faz com que os cookies SameSite=None sejam tratados inadvertidadamente como SameSite=Strict, e portanto não enviava solicitações entre sites, descrito aqui: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592.

Corrigi o problema apenas migrando para o .NET Core 3.1, existe um bug na versão 2.1 que não atribuía o valor "None" ao SameSite cookies.

Caso o erro persista você pode criar uma classe para identificar o dispositivo e definir a melhor atribuição para o SameSite coockie:
https://www.thinktecture.com/en/identity/samesite/prepare-your-identityserver/

Outra forma de corrigir o erro é criar um middleware que intercepta o redirecionamento da página:
https://www.thinktecture.com/en/identity/samesite/prepare-your-identityserver/